# Ruby on Rails: must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

This is my query.

```
ShopifyOrderLineItem.select("shopify_order_line_items.*, sum(amount) as total_price, sum(quantity) as total_quantity").where(:vendor_id => vendor_id).group("shopify_order_line_items.title")
```

I'm getting the following exception.

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "shopify_order_line_items.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT shopify_order_line_items.*, sum(amount) as total_pric...
```

Any suggestions?

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```
ShopifyOrderLineItem.select("shopify_order_line_items.*, count(shopify_order_line_items.id) as unique_ids, sum(amount) as total_price, sum(quantity) as total_quantity").where(:vendor_id => vendor_id).group("shopify_order_line_items.title")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to do a aggregation like SUM or COUNT, you can only select the columns on which you do the GROUP BY.

```
ShopifyOrderLineItem.select("shopify_order_line_items.title, count(shopify_order_line_items.id) as unique_ids, sum(amount) as total_price, sum(quantity) as total_quantity").where(:vendor_id => vendor_id).group("shopify_order_line_items.title")
```

Comment: What if I'm interested in other columns in shopify_order_line_items table that I don't want to group by?